# Gzip enabled but website not fully compressed

Tags: image, performance, fonts, compression, google-pagespeed

So I tested my website with pagespeed and I saw that I had alot of things to fix. One of the things that is highly prioritized is that I have to compress some fonts in my fonts folder because that reduces my website with 50%. The thing is that gzip is enabled but it won't disappear on pagespeed even though I enabled it. Does anyone know what the problem might be? My website is http://kashmaizat.se, the website configuration is based on apache and other information can be found [here](https://securityheaders.io/?q=kashmaizat.se&followRedirects=on)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to ask specific and self-contained questions, possibly showing code. Please edit the question and share your web server configuration (Apache?) and the generated HTTP headers.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. Here you got some information about my web server configuration etc. [Click here to view](https://securityheaders.io/?q=kashmaizat.se&followRedirects=on)

Comment: You need to enable `mod_gzip`: https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html. The fonts can be compressed with `gzip`: https://www.techonthenet.com/linux/commands/gzip.php

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that your website is already running at its most optimal speed. For example, it is only really worth compressing text-based file formats (i.e. HTML, CSS, JavaScript and XML).

For example, I have had a look at the HTTP response headers for a few of the images  in use on your website – they are being served without compression. Although I have not personally used Google PageSpeed, I would imagine that PageSpeed is deliberately serving your images uncompressed as this is the most efficient way of serving them for the end user. I would think that the reasoning behind this is that image file formats are already compressed by design; and compressing them again on the server and uncompressing on the client-side would have the adverse effect of making them take longer to download and render in the user’s browser.

I would imagine that, as with images, this is the case with font files too. As with images, EOT and WOFF files are already compressed by design. Google pride themselves on delivering a fast and efficient service and have gone to great lengths to research and implement this.

So, to answer your question: there is no problem with your website – in this case, I would advise not doing anything at all.

---

Here are a couple of links that may help:

- [Google PageSpeed: Insights - Optimize Images](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages)
- [Gzip your @font-face files](http://www.phpied.com/gzip-your-font-face-files/)